# WCF service to return JSON data to Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, wcf

I'm currently building a reporting service (WCF) - filled reports are produced using an [Elastic Object](http://elasticobject.codeplex.com/) which uses C# dynamics - I have written code to transform the object into JSON within the WCF service. The WCF service is hosted within a Windows Service and uses either named pipes or TCP bindings.

What I need to do next is to return the report object as JSON to an ASP.Net MVC web application which then just passes it through to the client without deserializing. I cannot have the client call the WCF service directly due to security issues.

Is this possible?

Comment: is it a REST service or SOAP service? r u making the calls from the client to  WCF through MVC?

Comment: If I was calling it directly from the client then I'd use REST - I have never seen an example of anyone trying to use REST with another server side layer in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - This was fairly straightforward in the end -

I followed this post [here](http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/), replacing my ElasticObject with the SerializableDynamicObject
(I didn't need the extended abilities of the ElasticObject)

This approach works nicely.